# Bean validations (jsr 303) with jax-rs / resteasy

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy

The [resteasy proposal](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Validation.html#d0e4058) to perform validations is to use a `@ValidateRequest` annotation in your jax-rs resource:

```
@Path("resourcePath")
@ValidateRequest
public interface Resource {
   @POST
   @Path("insert")
   public String insert(@Valid FormBean form);
}
```

But this **ties your code to a specific jax-rs implementation**, something I would like to avoid. Is there any generic way to use JSR 303 annotations to validate the incoming data?

Answer (score 0):

Try [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/jsr-303.html), which implements JSR-303 with the help of AspectJ. Should be easy to use in combination with JAX-RS.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to avoid new dependencies. I am already using Spring if you know any other alternative using AspectJ with Spring.